# Fritz!Box IPv6-Address different than IPv6-Prefix

Tags: networking, routing, router, ipv6

In my Fritzbox it states the following:

```
IPv6-Adresse: 2a02:8070:600::14b6:c7******, Gültigkeit: 100465/86065s
IPv6-Präfix:  2a02:8070:62c:3200::/56, Gültigkeit: 100464/86064s
```

I am not able to connect to IPv6 Addresses from computers configured by the fritzbox, because they get an address with prefix 2a02:8070:62c:3200::/56 but somehow the fritzbox does not route those addresses.

Is this because the **IPv6-Address is not in the prefix range**?

The address of the Fritzbox responds to pings, but my computers reached via various addresses from the prefix range do not (:

```
PING 2a02:8070:62c:3200:28d****(2a02:8070:62c:3200:28d****) 32 data bytes
From 2a02:8070:600:0:14b6*** icmp_seq=0 Destination unreachable: Administratively prohibited
From 2a02:8070:600:0:14b6*** icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Administratively prohibited
From 2a02:8070:600:0:14b6*** icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Administratively prohibited
From 2a02:8070:600:0:14b6*** icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Administratively prohibited
```

blocked ping this is "view" from outside

From inside the ping6 looks like this:

```
traceroute -6 heise.de
traceroute to heise.de (2a02:2e0:3fe:100::8), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
1  fritz.box (2a02:8070:62c:3200:****)  0.787 ms  1.424 ms  1.702 ms
2  * * *
......
30  * * *
```

Comment: You get `2a02:8070:600::14b6:c7******` on the link to the ISP (WAN side) and `2a02:8070:62c:3200::/56` to be used inside your own network (LAN side). That shouldn't cause the problem you are describing. Is there a way to see the routing table and the firewall settings of the Fritz!Box?

Comment: PS: good to see that Kabel Baden-Wuerttemberg GmbH is doing IPv6 :-)

Comment: no i cant find anything where i can see the routes in the fritzbox:(

Comment: `Administratively prohibited` does indicate that it's a firewall blocking the traffic

Comment: yeah from outside that is ok, but from inside i cant reach to outside.

Comment: I have seen firewalls that block *everything* by default, even outbound traffic. Maybe you need to explicitly allow it somewhere? (sorry, don't know enough details about the Fritz!Box to give better advise)

Comment: It worked yesterday, it just reconfigured itself, hope it is a routing issue with kabelbw

Comment: Got the same thing with a 7390 latest fm. But it with an HE tunnel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My settings were all correct, it seems like it was a issue in the network of Kabel BW but I can't say because I am no operator. It just started to work again.